# Azure Devops SSIS Package Deployment

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, ssis

We are trying to deploy an SSIS package via Azure devops to an on premise SQL server instance. I have done application deployment setups countless times but this is the first SQL on premise deployment we have tried using Azure devops. I have setup the azure agent and deployment groups etc

Is there a way to specify a different port for a SQL instance SSIS package deployment?

we are seeing the below error when trying to deploy a new package to a named SQL server that is running on a different port to the default 1433.

> Failed to connect to server DB-DEVMT-01\INST01. A connection was
> successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred
> during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The
> certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

In the logs, networks have found that connection is trying to go via 1433 but this obviously will not work so thinking if this can be specified in the agent job?

Or any other help with this error would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server is installed with self-signed certificates by default and it seems your connection string includes `;Encrypt=True`. Three choices come to mind: 1. remove `;Encrypt=true` from your connection string, 2. add `;TrustServerCertificate=true` to your connection string, or 3. open Manage Computer Certificates and copy (not move) SQL Server's public key from the Personal store to the Trusted Root Certificates store.

Comment: If SQL Browser is running on the machine, it should be able to redirect inbound requests to the correct port. Otherwise, assuming a stable port number, just define it in your connection string ala `DB-DEVMT-01\INST01:14333`